# Interpreting regex wildcards with grep

Tags: grep, regular-expression

This is a really simple question, but even after reading about wildcards/regex, I can't seem to *grasp* entirely what the differences between these commands are:

```
grep . test.txt
```

this one will look for lines containing any character in test.txt

```
grep \. test.txt
```

this one also apparently does the exact same thing, even though I assumed it shouldn't, since it would be escaped and return only those lines containing an actual '.'

```
grep ? test.txt
```

since ? is a special character, I guess it would be interpreted as a wildcard, but since grep doesn't deal with wildcards, it's not going to output anything;
however

```
grep \? test.txt
```

does find the lines which contain an '?' in them, but also those that contain an '\?' in them. Why is this?

Comment: In `grep \.`, the shell sees the backslash as an escape character, but a dot doesn't need escaping, so it's converted to `.`.  So both commands look the same to `grep`.  Try `grep '\.'`.

Comment: For `?` there are several things to point out.  First, `grep` gets to see the unescaped `?` because you don't have one-character filenames in the current directory.  Second, `\?` is expanded by the shell to `?`.  And third, `?` has no special meaning for `grep`.  It starts being special for `egrep`, or for `grep -E`, or `grep -P`.  Plain `grep` expects basic regexps (BRE), and `?` is nor special in the BRE dialect.